# Domain Chain Redirection

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, redirect, http-redirect

Does anyone experienced or tried to fix a redirect chain like this?:

From:

- http://www.damagerestorationservice.com (non-https with www )
- goingto https://www.damagerestorationservice.com (https with www )
- goingto https://damagerestorationservice.com (https without the www *final url* )

What I am trying to achieve is from

- http://www.damagerestorationservice.com
- then redirect straight to ( Remove the extra redirect )
- https://damagerestorationservice.com

*Additional Info: It is a wordpress website and hosted in Siteground*
*I didn't add any code my self, I only enabled the **free certificate ( let's encrypt )** inside the Siteground and enabled the **https for all url**.*

```
# HTTPS forced by SG-Optimizer
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: We would need to see the code that initiates the redirects. As your tags imply that would be the rewrite rules in your .htaccess. Your question is incomplete.

Comment: I'm not using any custom code from my end, I only enabled the free certificate ( let's encrypt ) inside the Siteground and enabled the https for all url.

Comment: You will probably have to edit your .htaccess file, but your first step is trying to investigate what is causing the redirects. Without a proper understanding of the current situation it is impossible to figure out how to make the changes you need to achieve what you want. I'd say just fire up you text editor and have a look at your .htaccess

Comment: I only have a default WP rules and added at the top are from Siteground. I also updated the orginal post

Answer (score 0):

Adding an extra rule to your .htaccess should do the trick. The new rule reacts when the domain `www.damagerestorationservice.com` is used without HTTPS, and redirects directly to `damagerestorationservice.com` with HTTPS. The first rewrite block will look like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.damagerestorationservice.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://damagerestorationservice.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I appreciate your response Thakkie, I tried to update htaccess and use your code but still not working. ( Cleared Cache in WP and use incognito browser ). See: https://snipboard.io/zeuZnt.jpg

Comment: Wow!, Cool!, wonder if this has something to do with hosting. ( I'll try it again on my end. )

Comment: No luck on my end, :( http://www.damagerestorationservice.com

Comment: Ah that would explain it. .htaccess file are (sort of) apache specific I failed to see your nginx tag.

Comment: Any idea how to do it for nginx?

Comment: nginx rewrite rules are usually in the site config file /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225491/discussion-between-thakkie-and-king-pangilinan).